# creating charts with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, charts

I've also been looking at charting solutions that will blend well with Angular.JS directives. I came across a few but got really confused. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to create interactive charts that are integrated with Angular.JS modules?

Comment: Given the posts below, would it make sense to accept one of them or are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[angular-charts](https://github.com/chinmaymk/angular-charts) is a library I wrote for creating charts with angular and [D3](http://d3js.org/).

It encapsulates basic charts that can be created using D3 in one angular directive. Also it offers features such as

1. One click chart change;
2. Auto tooltips;
3. Auto adjustment to containers;
4. Legends;
5. Simple data format: only define what you on x and what you need on y;

There is a [angular-charts demo](http://chinmaymk.github.io/angular-charts/) available.

Comment: looks good, but i guess that i miss something there. i cannot make it loaded. in the installation guide it is written "Dependencies: Angular and d3", and "Install using bower" - what does it mean? i have to include D3? and what is bower?

Comment: i get this error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: angularChartsProvider <- angularCharts

Comment: You don't need to inject angularCharts into your controller. Just work with $scope to give it the data that the directive needs in the HTML.

Comment: are there 2 versions of angular-charts - i see one that uses d3 and another that uses chart.js

Comment: @Winter, yes there are two different things.

Comment: DRAWBACK:Requirejs support is not available in angular-charts right now.

Comment: Unfortunately the angular-charts community is pretty dead and issues do not get resolved. I was relying on it for a business application but may have to pull the plug and move to angular chart instead http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

Comment: Can you see my question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256487/i-want-to-change-the-chart-for-each-city-or-subcity-selected

Comment: Can the angular charts be used offline?

Answer (score 16):

I've seen some nice AngularJS charting solutions that make use of [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com). There's a [highcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng) directive on GitHub to make AngularJS integration easier, and [some](http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/Hjdnw/) [examples](http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/7cAq3/) on JSFiddle to give you a quick taste of what's possible.

You set up the chart on the JS side like this:

```
$scope.chart = {
    options: {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Hello'
    },
    loading: false
}
```

And then refer to it in the HTML like this:

```
<highchart id="chart1" config="chart"></highchart>
```

Usage/licensing warning: Highcharts is available for free under the Creative Commons license for non-commercial use. If you're looking for charting options in a for-profit/commercial scenario, you'll need to buy the product or look elsewhere.

Comment: Author of highcharts-ng here. See a comprehensive demo at: http://pablojim.github.io/highcharts-ng/examples/example.html

Answer (score 16):

The [ZingChart library](http://www.zingchart.com) has an [AngularJS directive](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/reference/angularjs-charts) that was built in-house. Features include:

- Full access to the entire ZingChart library (all charts, maps, and features)
- Takes advantage of Angular's 2-way data binding, making data and chart elements easy to update
- Support from the development team

  ```
  ...
  $scope.myJson = {
  type : 'line',
     series : [
        { values : [54,23,34,23,43] },{ values : [10,15,16,20,40] }
     ]
  };
  ...

  <zingchart id="myChart" zc-json="myJson" zc-height=500 zc-width=600></zingchart>
  ```

There is a [full demo with code examples](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/reference/angularjs-charts) available.

Comment: Seems like you're affiliated with ZingCharts. That would've been appropriate to state up front.

Comment: At the time of posting, that was the directive I had experience with and felt comfortable recommending. 

In any case, thank you for your meaningful contribution to this thread!

Answer (score 6):

Did you try D3.js? Here is a good [example](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-d3.html).

Comment: This gets upvoted? It is plain JS.  There are wrappers, but this might be the best place to start - in the official ng-newsletter ... http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html

Answer (score 5):

I've created an angular directive for xCharts which is a nice js chart library http://tenxer.github.io/xcharts/. You can install it using bower, quite easy:
https://github.com/radu-cigmaian/ng-xCharts

Highcharts is also a solution, but it is not free for comercial use.

Answer (score 3):

To collect more useful resources here:

As mentioned before D3.js is definitely the best visualization library for charts. To use it in AngularJS I developed [angular-chart](https://github.com/maxklenk/angular-chart). It is an easy to use directive which connects D3.js with the AngularJS 2-Way-DataBinding. This way the chart gets automatically updated whenever you change the configuration options and at the same time the charts saves its state (zoom level, ...) to make it available in the AngularJS world.

Check out the [examples](http://maxklenk.github.io/angular-chart/) to get convinced.

Comment: afraid the link is broken

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS charting plugin along with FusionCharts library to add interactive JavaScript graphs and charts to your web/mobile applications - with just a single directive. Link: http://www.fusioncharts.com/angularjs-charts/#/demos/ex1